# AddBehavior & navigateFrame (Open With Explorer) SP2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, open-with-explorer

I have been facing an issue with "Open With Explorer" and well, restarting WebClient service helps sometimes, restarting my PC also helps sometimes, but that is totally not handy.

I have taken a very closer look to the JavaScript code that is called when I click "Open with Explorer". And I found that there is a function called NavigateHttpFolderCore() in the **core.js** file.

Inside that function there is the following:

```
httpFolderDiv = document.createElement("DIV");    

document.body.appendChild(httpFolderDiv);
httpFolderDiv.onreadystatechange = NavigateHttpFolderCore;        
httpFolderDiv.addBehavior("#default#httpFolder");

httpFolderDivTest.navigateFrame("htps://sharepoint.com/sites/site1/docLib", "_blank");
```

The code above is just an example and I would like to focus on:

- [addBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535922(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [httpFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531419(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [navigateFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531397(v=vs.85).aspx)

Once I call addBehavior and parse #default#httpFolder
I am able to call navigateFrame.

navigateFrame returns either "OK", if successful, meaning that the "Open With Explorer" will indeed **Open in Windows Explorer**, or it returns "FAILED" and the "Your client does not support..." will pop up on my screen.

My question here is, why navigateFrame returns sometimes "OK" and sometimes "FAILED"?

And, am I able to "see" inside navigateFrame in order to understand the different return values?